# dotnet build xamarin project fails using console

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, asp.net-core, azure-pipelines

When I try to build my `.csproj` file with dotnet it throws an error, but when I build project at Visual Studio 2019 it succeeds.

I need to build with `dotnet` because my Azure pipeline job uses it.

This is the error:

```
dotnet build MyProject.Mobile.Droid.csproj --configuration Release --force

MyProject.Mobile.Droid.csproj(584,3): error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets was not found. Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.100\\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.CSharp.targets" is correct, and the file exists on disk.

Build FAILED.
```

(Also as [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fs4Wu.png).)

If I set the path parameter in my `.csproj` to this:

```
<MSBuildExtensionsPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild</MSBuildExtensionsPath>
```

Then the error changes:

```
The reference assemblies for MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application. You can download .NET Framework Developer Packs at https://aka.ms/msbuild/developerpacks
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use `msbuild` (like `msbuild MySolution.sln`) to build a Xamarin project today.

You can build the individual `netstandard2.x` projects using `dotnet build`, however the Mono based platform projects (i.e. the Android and iOS projects) need to be built using `msbuild`.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the `TargetFrameworkRootPath` to where you have xamarin installed.

```
<TargetFrameworkRootPath>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\</TargetFrameworkRootPath>
```

or on the command line

```
dotnet build -clp:ErrorsOnly -p:MSBuildExtensionsPath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild"/ -p:TargetFrameworkRootPath="C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/Common7/IDE/ReferenceAssemblies/Microsoft/Framework/"
```

Comment: how about using macOS instead of Windows?

Comment: according to ChatGPT, the equivalent command for macOS would be `dotnet build -clp:ErrorsOnly -p:MSBuildExtensionsPath="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin" -p:TargetFrameworkRootPath="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/lib/mono/xbuild-frameworks`, but I haven't tested it yet

Comment: @user1623521 unfortunately, the command above is not working